# jQuery: Need to prevent repetitive 'space bar' input

Tags: jquery, forms, input, keycode

Apologies if this is a simple question, relatively new JavaScript/jQuery coder. What I am looking to do is validation on an input field (postcode entry), after the user press the spacebar once they are unable to press it again.

I understand how to prevent the spacebar from any input entry, but unable to grasp how to do so after maximum one press.

---

**EDIT:** @cosmo0 here is what I begun to try similar to @hamed but utilising something I saw on another website:

```
var spacePress = 0;
$('#StreamUrl').keypress(function(event){     
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '32'){
        nbr++;  
    }else if( nbr == 1){
        event.keyCode
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:** I believe I have come to a positive result

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="inputBox" class="input" autocomplete="off"/>
<p id="key"></p>
<p id="textField"></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
var value;
var spaceCount = 0;

$( '.input' ).keydown(function(e){
    var value = $( '.input' ).val();
    if( e.keyCode == 32 ){
        spaceCount ++;
        console.log( 'Space count at ' + spaceCount );
    }
    if( e.keyCode == 32 && spaceCount > 1 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(value == ""){
        spaceCount = 0;
    }
    $( '#key' ).text(spaceCount);
    $( '#textField' ).text(value);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/georgesofroniou/vsct71px/3/)

I think this could be improved as when I initially clear the input field the spaceCount is not set to 0 until I type a keyCode that !=  32.

Thanks for your help everyone :)

---

**EDIT 2**
Thanks to @Adjit, I think I have found a better solution. Weirdly his jQuery code was not working but the JavaScript was (I am going to double check code to see if I had any inconsistencies). However I did include the addition of something extra, which is to prevent the user from entering a space if this is the first character of input.

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('myInput').onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32 && this.value.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = "Already a space!";
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if( e.keyCode == 32 && this.value.length == 0 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/georgesofroniou/vsct71px/7/)

Comment: Have you tried something already ?

Comment: Hi @cosmo0, yes I have tried a few things, but honestly nothing worthwhile posting. My initial thought was if the value contains a " " then prevent.Default(), but I was still in process of trying to get this to function. I thought of something similar to hamed however I could not articulate the code I needed for functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a better way to do this without any counters or anything - AND it can be done with pure Javascript

**JQuery**

```
$('#myInput').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32 && $(this).val().indexOf(' ') >= 0){
        $('#key').text('Already a space!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Javascript Equivalent**

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 32 && this.value.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = "Already a space!";
    return false;
  }
  else document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />
<span id="key"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Adjit, this is a really intuitive way of achieving this! I have however achieved it with a slight edit to the way I initially was trying and Hamed's

Comment: @GSof yeah, however, I try not to use global variables when I do not need to. Also, there is one inherent caveat to all of this, which I just thought of. And that is - what if the user erases the space? Thinking about a solution for this now.

Comment: @GSof solved the problem and made your code a little more abridged. Only need 1 if statement and you don't need any counters.

Comment: Thanks @Adjit, currently I'm not on my laptop. But will definitely give this a try seems a great solution! So the code above simplifies what I was trying to do and also eradicates the issue of user erasing a space?

Comment: @GSof that is correct. I got rid of the first section of my answer, because it is essentially what others have said. The Javascript looks a bit messier - but that is just the nature of JS. So if you were importing JQuery just for this one thing I would say you don't need to do that.

Comment: apologies late reply only just been able to get to my laptop. I did just try the jQuery and unfortunately this did not work - it did not prevent the spacebar? I agree with your point about jQuery/JavaScript, this is not the only function in jQuery so that is not an issue. **Edit** however the JavaScript functions, is that what you meant apologies?

Comment: @GSof no worries with the late reply. The jQuery posted above does work for me. Not sure what you mean about the JavaScript functions, but I was just saying if this was the only script you had, even though jQuery is cleaner than JS, I don't think it would be worth importing the jQuery library just for 1 function.

Comment: I was agreeing with your statement about not using jQuery for just 1 function. However I already have other jQuery function. I have managed to get the jQuery code functioning, I changed the return false for event.preventDefault() - I put an edit in my original question of my solution :) thanks again Adjit

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use jquery [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)  event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var spaceCount = 0;
   $("#inputId").keydown(function (e) {

       //space code is 32
       if (e.keyCode == 32)
         spaceCount ++;

       if(spaceCount == 2)
         e.preventDefault();

       else return true;


    });
});
```

Comment: issue being your second if statement prevents the default of any key not the spacebar specifically alone. This was the issue I encountered. Thank you for your help it has been greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the end you just want there to be one space in between words instead of multiple spaces? Why don't you just wait till the user tries to submit the form and then remove all the extra spaces with:

```
var string = string.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/29jj2hu7/1/)

Where `string` is the *input valuet*.

**EDIT:**

I removed the on key event for detecting spaces, because there are a lot of ifs and conditions that need to be tested.

1. You need a global `boolean` variable initiated at `false`
2. Once a space is detected with `.on('keypress'`... you set the boolean to true.
3. If the variable is true and a space is detected then you do `e.preventDefault()` to stop it from being added into the input.
4. If a backspace was pressed you need to memorize the location of all previous spaces to know if the backspace removes or precedes a space.

Comment: Thanks for this @Grimbode, unfortunately due to customer requirements we cannot allow any multiple spaces at all, even though what you say completely makes sense